# Como alinhar menu utilizando CSS (Apenas)

Tags: css, html5, css3, css-hover

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um site e, após conseguir criar um menu dropdown, tive um pequeno problema. O mesmo não está espaçado, e o sub menu que surge está disposto na horizontal.
Não tenho interesse em colocar borda  e etc, porém, preciso de ajuda para dispor o menu de forma que ele fique alinhado e preencha a página. Alguém pode ajudar?
(Ainda irei inserir divs e restante da página).

```css
body{
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
}
 
ul{
 color:#008000;
 float:left;
 display:inline-block;
 font-size: 18px;
 
}

li{
 float:left;
}

li ul{
 position: absolute;
 display: none;

}

li:hover ul, li.over ul{
 display:block;
 
}

li ul li{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
 <head>
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Teste</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="estilo.css" /> 
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <img src="TCM_logo.jpg" width="20%" height="20%">
  <a href=""<img src="images.png" width="2%" =height="2%" align="right"></a>
 </div>
  <br>
  
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
        <li>
         <a>Historia</a>
        </li>

        <li>
         <a>Localização</a>
        </li>

            <li>
             <a href="produtos.html">Produtos</a>
                <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Dietas</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#"></a>Fórmulas
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#"></a>Suplementos
     </li>
     <li><a href="#"></a>Equipos
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#"></a>Frascos
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#"></a>Fraldas
     <li/>
    </ul>
            </li>

         <li>
          <a>Trabalhe Conosco</a>
         </li>
         
         <li>
          <a href="contato.html">Contato</a>
         </li>                
</ul>
</nav>
<br>

<div>
 <img src="telao.png" width = "1049" height="300">
</div>
<div>
 <a href="produtos.html">aadkjsadj</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cara sua pergunta está meio confusa. Como assim vc quer que o Menu preencha a página? Vc tem alguma imagem do layout de como está ai e de como deveria ter que ficar? Edite sua resposta explicando melhor os detalhes

Comment: Irei editar. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde amigo.

Não sei se é só isso que você precisa, mas para deixar os itens do sub-menu listados na vertical, adicione um clear: both nos elementos li's do menu. Seguindo seu código, basta adicionar o clear dentro do seletor que você esta utilizando.

```
li ul li{
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Tomo a liberdade para sugerir que você adicione classes em alguns elementos, por exemplo no sub-menu, de tal forma que você consiga acessá-los de forma mais fácil.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando a propriedade `display: flex` em conjunto com a propriedade `justify-content` você consegue uma melhor manipulação sobre os elementos do 'container', que no caso seria a tag `ul`. Basta adicionar o seguinte código no seu estilo.

```
ul {
  width: 100%; /* Faz ocupar o espaço inteiro da tag pai, que seria o nav */
  display: flex; /* Transforma em um container flexível */
  justify-content: space-between; /* Separa os elementos igualmente entre eles */
}
```

[Tutotial online sobre flex](https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/)

[Seu exemplo funcionando com flex](https://jsfiddle.net/zp3co92n/)